# How can I let Analytics know my query is not finish before a utm code?

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm trying to use a utm for a query on my page but sadly the url is like this:

*comprar/es/torres/busqueda?searchTerm=103005+103004+125043+125042*

The question mark inside prevents the use of the utm to track it,

¿Is there an equivalent to the backslash \ of RegEx that allow me to state that the first ? is still part of the query url string?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your URL? Is it `?searchTerm=103005+103004+125043+125042?utm=something`?

Comment: Yes is: domainname.com/comprar/es/torres/busqueda?searchTerm=103005+103004+125043+125042

Comment: Where's the `utm` parameter? Also it is better to monitor your question more then once per eight days.

Answer (score 1):

the anwser to this is to set the utm as an extra parameter after the variables of the site

If this is the original URL:

```
mydomain.com/a/busqueda?searchTerm=103005+103004+125043+125042
```

You have to set it like this:

```
mydomain.com/a/busqueda?searchTerm=103005+103004+125043+125042&utm_source=sample&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify if work: comprar%2Fes%2Ftorres%2Fbusqueda%3FsearchTerm%3D103005%2B103004%2B125043%2B125042

You can use "Campaign URL Builder", site: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/

Comment: Thanks, this is the only thing that actually gave me something to work with. It doesn't exist for the utm a character that lets you state that the query is not finish. The next best thing is that use the # instead of the ? but you have to choose between loosing the capability of registering the queries or the anchors. Thankyou for helping!